Вычисление точного обратного синуса угла в sympy
Есть строка, например '7+asin(0.8-0.3)'. Если поместить её внутрь print(simplify(parse_expr()).evalf(32)), sympy выводит значение обратного синуса в радианах, но даже если дополнять строку методом deg: '7+deg(asin(0.8-0.3))', то при выводе получается 37.000000000000001092276223729355, тогда как ожидалось просто 37. Как решить эту проблему без округления?

Дело не в точности вычислений, а в точности представления вещественных чисел - число Pi/6 невозможно предcтавить в формате float или double. Для прочтения. P.S. Однако вижу, что вам уже описывали суть проблемы...

Никак. Смиритесь. Компьютеры не умеют считать точно. Ошибки округления были, есть и будут.

@PakUula, это simpy, а она иногда умеет считать точно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy у топик стартера написано evalf(32) - численное вычисление, в отличие от точного символьного.

@PakUula, полагаю он не знает всех способностей sympy и неудачно ею воспользовался.

@StanislavVolodarskiy вот-вот. Чтобы в sympy получить точно значение, нужно хорошо понимать, что такое символьные вычисления, а не использовать эту мега-штуку только для parse_expr

Выражение '7 + asin(0.8 - 0.3)' содержит вещественные десятичные дроби. sympy в этом случае считает выражение приближённо. Если попросить sympy.simplify представлять десятичные дроби рациональными числами (флаг rational=True), результаты станут точными:

@>>> simplify('7 + asin(0.8 - 0.3)', rational=True)
pi/6 + 7
@>>> simplify('7 + deg(asin(0.8 - 0.3))', rational=True)
37


Или можно заменить десятичные дроби на обыкновенные:

@>>> simplify('7 + asin(8/10 - 3/10)')
pi/6 + 7
@>>> simplify('7 + deg(asin(8/10 - 3/10))')
37



В качестве альтернативной идеи (вывод: 37.0):
import os
import math

result = eval('7 + (math.asin(0.8 - 0.3) * (180 / math.pi))')

print(f"Результат: {result}")

print("\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul" if os.name == "nt" else "read > /dev/null")


А зачем здесь eval, без него тоже самое же получается?

Может и получается. Но в одной из подобных тем уже затрагивалась тема точности. Выяснилось, что обработка строк точнее, чем уже готовых чисел. Кроме того, строка записана в условии. Я дополнил её другой частью, из тех же соображений точности обработки текстовых строк, и затем уж вычислял.

Карго-культ какой-то

Вам известно значение этого термина? Не знаю, какой там культ, но у меня работает, просто и без заумных модулей.

@andreymal А я то думаю что за чудеса. Но разбираться было лениво.

Можно смеяться? А) мне начхать на подробности, важен результат; Б) именно потому и использую эти приколы, что УМЕЮ считать и УМЕЮ этими приколами пользоваться. В банке этому учили.

Повторю удалившийся комментарий — оно «работает», потому что сложение с числом 7 отбрасывает погрешности, перестающие влезать в мантиссу 64-битного вещественного числа. Меняем входящие условия хотя бы немного, например, заменой 7 на 1 — и ой

Я не считаю эти рассуждения хоть сколько-нибудь  существенными, важными и нужными. Это не уровень владения компьютерной математикой, это Ваша точка зрения.

@FoxFox, я уважаю вашу прямолинейность и настойчивость. Этот ответ я бы удалил. В комментариях CrazyElf и andreymal есть рациональное зерно.

С чего вдруг? В моём варианте РАБОТАЕТ! Это раз. Не задействуется модуль, название которого лично я услышал в первый раз. Это два. Покажите, что этот подход неправильный, я с удовольствием почитаю. Я умею учиться, но думаю своей головой, всегда.

Умеете учиться, но не хотите разбираться, зачем вообще используется sympy. Интересно )

Вот и разбирайтесь. Если время некуда девать. Я не колю орехи кувалдой, есть попроще для этого инструменты. В данном случае так точно есть. Мне прям сейчас садиться и читать документацию по всем на свете модулям?

Конечно, это уже оффтопик, но если вы не хотите вечно изобретать велосипеды, то хотя бы общее представление зачем используется тот или иной популярный модуль нужно иметь.

Зачем Вы это пишете? Мой код на полтора километра? Он длиннее или сложнее приведенных выше? Не нравится?! Так используйте свой либо какой-либо другой! Для этого тут и существует конкуренция ответов! Я не могу понять вот этой писанины. Кто заставляет пользоваться моим ответом? Вот я хочу и шоб все писали о том модуле, который мне нравится!!! Потому что МНЕ нравится и всё! Этот принцип? Никаких вразумительных возражений относительно альтернативы при этом я так и не увидел.
